# Input element's value in react component is not getting re-rendered when the state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My state object is a Map
`const [voucherSet, setVoucherSet] = useState(initialVoucherSet);`

initialVoucherSet is map I create at the beginning of the stateless component function.

```
    const initialVoucherSet = new Map();
    activeVoucher.voucherDenominations.forEach(voucherDemonination=> {
        initialVoucherSet.set(voucherDemonination, 0);
    });
    const [voucherSet, setVoucherSet] = useState(initialVoucherSet);
```

`activeVoucher.voucherDenominations` an array of numbers.

I have a input which triggers a function on onChange.

```
    const handleChange = (e)=>{
        const voucherDemonination = parseInt(e.target.id);
        const voucherQuantity = parseInt(e.target.value);
        if (voucherQuantity >= 0) { setVoucherSet(voucherSet.set(voucherDemonination, voucherQuantity)); }
    }
```

The state object voucherSet is getting updated, but my input's value is not getting re-rendered.

Below is the input element:

```
<CounterInput type='number'  id={voucherDemonination} onChange={handleChange} value={voucherSet.get(voucherDemonination)} />
```

***What I already tried***
I thought that it might be because I was not setting a different object to the voucherSet state variable. So I tried something a bit hacky...

```
    const handleChange = (e)=>{
        const voucherDemonination = parseInt(e.target.id);
        const voucherQuantity = parseInt(e.target.value);
        if (voucherQuantity >= 0) { 
            const tempVoucherSet = voucherSet;
            tempVoucherSet.set(voucherDemonination, voucherQuantity);
            setVoucherSet(tempVoucherSet); 
         }
    }
```

but it still didn't work.

Where am I wrong?
Much Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what is happening is that the Map itself is not changing (eg. every time you update the Map, you still have a reference to the same exact Map in memory), so react is not rerendering.

This falls under the whole "immutable" thing with react. Any time a state change happens, a new object or array ow whatever should be created so that react and easily detect that something changed and thus rerender. This makes it so react doesn't have to iterate over every key in your object/array to see if anything changed (which would kill your performance).

Try this in the code which updates your map:

```
tempVoucherSet.set(voucherDemonination, voucherQuantity);
setVoucherSet(new Map(tempVoucherSet)); // -> notice the new Map()
```

This is analogous to other code you may have seen with react and state changes where new objects/arrays are created any time a new property/item is added:

```
setState({ ...oldState, newProperty: 'newValue' })
setState([ ...oldArray, newItem ]);
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan! ..and thanks again for explaining the theory!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in the past. Set your state this way:

```
setVoucherSet(new Map(voucherSet.set(voucherDemonination, voucherQuantity)));
```

That will cause a re-render.